# Ordenamiento alfabetico c#

Tags: c#, array, string

Tengo un programa en C#, que ingresando nombres de tres países con sus respectivas temperaturas, calcula la temperatura media anual de cada uno. Luego los imprime de manera ordenada alfabéticamente. Al finalizar, imprime el país con la temperatura media trimestral mayor.

Mi consulta precisa es la siguiente:

¿Cómo ordeno alfabéticamente en C#?

**Ejemplo:**

Entrada

> Bolivia, Argentina, Albania.

Salida

> Albania, Argentina, Bolivia.

Intenté desarrollándolo de esta manera, pero no hubo caso:

```
public void ImprimirTempTrimestrales()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Las temperaturas trimestrales: ");
    for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < 3 - 1 - c; f++)
        {
            if (paises[f].CompareTo(paises[f + 1]) > 0)
            {
                string auxpais;
                auxpais = paises[f];
                paises[f] = paises[f + 1];
                paises[f + 1] = auxpais;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(paises[f] + " " + temptri[f]);
        }
    }
}
```

**Todo el código:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Matriz
 {
  class Matriz
   {
    private string[] paises;
    private int[,] tempmen;
    private int[] temptri;

    public void Cargar()
    {
        paises = new String[3];
        tempmen = new int[4, 3];
        for (int f = 0; f < paises.Length; f++)
        {
            Console.Write("Ingrese nombre del país:");
            paises[f] = Console.ReadLine();
            for (int c = 0; c < tempmen.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write("Ingrese temperatura mensual:");
                string linea = Console.ReadLine();
                tempmen[f, c] = int.Parse(linea);
            }
        }
    }

    public void ImprimirTempMensuales()
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < paises.Length; f++)
        {
            Console.Write("Pais:" + paises[f] + ":");
            for (int c = 0; c < tempmen.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                Console.Write(tempmen[f, c] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    public void CalcularTemperaturaAnual()
    {
        temptri = new int[12];
        for (int f = 0; f < tempmen.GetLength(0); f++)
        {
            int suma = 0;
            for (int c = 0; c < tempmen.GetLength(1); c++)
            {
                suma = suma + tempmen[f, c];
            }
            temptri[f] = suma / 12;
        }
    }

    public void ImprimirTempTrimestrales()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Las temperaturas trimestrales: ");
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
        {
            for (int f = 0; f < 3 - 1 - c; f++)
            {
                if (paises[f].CompareTo(paises[f + 1]) > 0)
                {
                    string auxpais;
                    auxpais = paises[f];
                    paises[f] = paises[f + 1];
                    paises[f + 1] = auxpais;

                }

                Console.WriteLine(paises[f] + " " + temptri[f]);
            }
        }
    }
    public void PaisMayorTemperaturaTri()
    {
        int may = temptri[0];
        string nom = paises[0];
        for (int f = 0; f < paises.Length; f++)
        {
            if (temptri[f] > may)
            {
                may = temptri[f];
                nom = paises[f];
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("El pais que tiene la temperatura trimestral mayor es: " + nom + " y es de: " + may);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Matriz10 ma = new Matriz10();
        ma.Cargar();
        ma.ImprimirTempMensuales();
        ma.CalcularTemperaturaAnual();
        ma.ImprimirTempTrimestrales();
        ma.PaisMayorTemperaturaTri();
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
  }
}
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Dejando aparte la respuesta (que es correcta), si quieres ver como se hace a mano existen muchos algoritmos de ordenación (burbuja, quicksort, mergesort) bien documentados y explicados. Buscar algunos de ellos y ver como funcionan puede ayudar a familiarizarse un poco a coger soltura con el diseño de algoritmos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si ya tienes un array con la lista de paises, bastaría llamar al método de LINQ `OrderBy()`:

```
var paisesOrdenados = paises.OrderBy(x => x);
```

Cabe resaltar que `paisesOrdenados` será un `IOrderedEnumerable<string>` si quieres almacenarlo también en un array puedes usar al final `.ToArray()`

```
var paisesOrdenados = paises.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Si quieres modificar la misma variable solo reemplaza la anterior.

```
paises = paises.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Otra forma sería pasando los valores del array a un `List<string>` y luego llamando al método `.Sort()`.

```
var paisesList = paises.ToList();
paisesList.Sort();
```

Comment: Me salvaste la vida. Muchas gracias!